# Multi-Tenant Sequence generator in Hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, hql

I have a Client entity with orgId and clientId as a composite key. When I have to insert a new client object, I have to generate clientId id sequentially for each orgId, so to do that, I am generating clientId by maintaining the last clientId of every orgId in a separate table, and selecting, adding 1, and updating it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ftb_client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")
    protected String orgId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID")
    protected int clientId;

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_NAME_ENG")
    private String clientNameEng;
//....
}

@Entity
@Table
public class MySeq implements Serializable {
    @Id
    protected String orgId;

    private int lastClientId;
//....
}

public Long getNewClientId(String orgId) {
    MySeq mySeq = getSession()
            .createQuery("from MySeq where orgId = :orgId", MySeq.class)
            .setParameter("orgId", orgId)
            .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
            .uniqueResult();

    mySeq.setLastClientId(mySeq.getLastClientId() + 1);

    return mySeq.getLastClientId();
}
```

But, this leads to duplicate id generation if there are thousands of concurrent requests. So, to make it thread-safe I have to use Pessimistic locking, so that multiple requests do not generate the same clientId. But now, the problem is that lock doesn't get released until the transaction ends and concurrent requests keep pending for a long time.

So instead of using a lock, if I could use a separate sequence per orgId then I could make the id generation concurrent too. I want to manually execute the sequence generator by determining the sequence name in the runtime by doing something like client_sequence_[orgId] and execute it to generate the id.

And I also want to make it database-independent, or at least for Oracle, MySQL, and Postgres.

I want to know if it is possible or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you use `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` or not, a lock will be acquired anyway if you update the entity. The difference is that the lock is acquired eagerly in the case you describe here which prevents lost writes.

Usually, this is solved by creating a separate transaction for the sequence increment. To improve performance, you should increment by a batching factor i.e. 10 and keep 10 values in a queue in-memory to serve from. When the queue is empty, you ask for another 10 values etc.

Hibernate implements this behind the scenes with the `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator` along with `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizer`. So if you know the sequences that you need upfront, I would recommend you use these tools for that purpose. You can also do something similar though yourself if you like.